# Cordova - Download image and move it into another folder

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, download, move

I'm currently trying to download an image and then moving it to a directory on the sdcard.

I have this code to download the image:

```
utils.download = function (url, success, fail) {
var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
var uri = encodeURI(url);
var store = cordova.file.dataDirectory + "_temp/";
fileTransfer.download(uri,
    store + "wallpaper.jpg",
    function(res){success(res);},
    function(res){fail(res);});
};
```

This works perfectly fine.

Now I need to move the file (to `file://mnt/sdcard/FolderName/wallpaper.png`). But there's not a single word about moving files in the Cordova file documentation, so I'm very confused on how to do this... Anybody can help me there?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prototype of function : Line 107 @ [cordova-file-plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file/blob/master/www/Entry.js)

Untested example. but will most likely work!

```
function moveFile(fileUri, destDir) {
    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(
        fileUri,
        function(fileEntry) {
            newFileName = "myfile.data";
            window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(destDir,
                function(dirEntry) {
                    fileEntry.moveTo(dirEntry, newFileName, successCallback, errorCallback);
                },
                errorCallback);
        },
        errorCallback);
}
```

Comment: So `fileUri` is a string like `file:///data/data/com.myapp/files/folder/wallpaper.png`, right? Thank you!

Comment: @krmax44 yes std cordova file uri